# Sextante grass folder incorrect?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sextante

What is the correct grass folder in Sextante?

I always get this message:

> The specified GRASS folder does not contain a valid set of GRASS
> modules. Please, go to the SEXTANTE settings dialog, and check that
> the GRASS folder is correctly configured

This is the current sextante grass folder. I did not change anything after the Osgeo4W installation. I guess that the path isn’t correct.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you configure the GRASS folder for the sextante plugin.

If you click **Analysis --> SEXTANTE options and configuration** you can define the paths to your GRASS installation.

My path is: **C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2**

I´m using Sextante 1.0.9 for QGIS, which comes with its own GRASS installation

Comment: I'm using 1.0.9, too. The grass folder in sextante came up with the installation. Should the grass folder be in the Osgeo4w folder?

Comment: I don´t think it matters in which folder the GRASS installation is, as long as the SEXTANTE configuration points to that folder. Do you have a similar path to the one I have in your configuration and does the folder exist?

Comment: I tried your path settings but without any success.

Comment: If you use exactely the path I used, it will not work. It´s cut off. You have to find the folder where your GRASS GIS is installed and use its path.

Comment: What is the grass staring file (exe, bat?). Which file should be in the folder to start grass in sextante?

Comment: I´m not sure which file is necessary. What path are you using currently in your SEXTANTE configuration?

Comment: This is my folder in sextante: 
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2

Comment: Is there another GRASS GIS folder inside the folder where QGIS is installed ? EXAMPLE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2

Comment: Yes I have a folder like that and I tried it before. The result was quiet the same. The interesting thing is, that some tools  work fine and other tools course python errors. Some saga tools and some grass tools do not work.